# Rails associations - Users has many Users through Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to design a comment system allowing users to post on other users' pages, through comments.

A user will have a comment on his page, which is posted by another user called "commenter."

1) Is the following code legit/functional/decent design?

2) Is it OK to have a renamed "commenter" user, in conjunction with an un-renamed "user", or should all association names of user always be renamed semantically?

3) Are there better ways to implement this design intent (e.g. not doing a has_many through:)?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :users,      through: :comments
  has_many :commenters, through: :comments, class_name: 'User'  
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commenter, class_name: 'User'
end
```

NOTE:

I wish to allow users to comment on users, but also on other models, (e.g. characters, celebrities). So I would think having the comments table be used in various has_many through associations is called for.

users       has many commenters through comments
characters  has many commenters through comments
celebrities has many commenters through comments

Comment: Please, mark the answer you found more helpful as accepted.

Comment: Im still looking to see a solution with rails. I haven't had time to try that gem or test the rails code. I'm a bit reluctatnt. to mark now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your design is not going to work as it is - you are mixing has_many with has_many through. If I were you I would use an approach like this one:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_comments, class_name: 'Comments', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_many :posted_comments, class_name: 'Comments', foreign_key: 'commenter_id'
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :commenter, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Comment: I thought it was typically better to have the "belonging" mode contain keys of the owning models.

I do want to put other attributes to the comment model and use the comment model as its separate entity, which is why i chose has_many through.

I also wish to allow users to comment on other tables, like on characters and celebrities, so I wish to accomodate designs to expand.

I will update the original question to reflect this.

Comment: can i just remove `has_many :comments`, and keep the rest to be has_many through?

Comment: Technically is possible to implemented with the has_many through, it just that sounds a bit weird for me to use it for Users' Comments. But you understand better how your app will grown so it is up to you. If you want also to comment in other models you can use a polymorphic association, e.g. in Comment class  `belongs_to :target, polymorphic: true` where the target will be character, celebrities, etc. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: I also came to the conclusion of polymorphic comments between the last post and now. =]

Comment: how does "owned_comments" and "posted_comments" get recognized a names? can you just add any name with an underscore to the name of a model that belongs to a user, and have it recognized without explicitly naming that new name in the comments model?

Comment: Yes, you can put whatever name you want for your relations, as long as you specify the class_name and the foreign_key like I did, e.g. `has_many :owned_comments, class_name: 'Comments', foreign_key: 'owner_id'`

Answer (score 1):

have to tried acts_as_commentable gem it give lot of other options as well like public,private comment https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable

Comment: is there a good place where i can see the functionality, features, drawbacks?

Comment: you won't find any drawbacks as such even if you google it, but it's very popular gem for commenting and will serve you most for this purpose

Comment: also act_as_comment gem makes use of model name which allows you to make use of same comment model on multiple model as per your comment for using comment table on characters,celebrities you will just have to add act_as_commetable in the model in which you want to use it rest all will be handled bu the gem itself

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a similar functionality in mongoid and rails. The models were User, Friendship and Request. Its like User sends friend request to another user.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
    :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
  ...
  has_many :requests_from, class_name: "Request", inverse_of: :requested_by
  has_many :requests_to, class_name: "Request", inverse_of: :requested_to
  has_many :friendships, inverse_of: :owner

  def friends
    #retrive all the friendships and collect users have sent me a request or being sent a request.
    fs = Friendship.any_of({:friend_id.in => [self.id]}, {:owner_id.in => [self.id]}).where(state: 'accepted')
    User.in(id: fs.collect{|i| [i.friend_id, i.owner_id]}.flatten - [self.id])
  end
end#User

class Friendship
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :state, type: String, default: 'pending'
  field :pending, type: Boolean, default: true

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"

  validates :state, inclusion: { in: ["pending", "accepted", "rejected"]}
  ...
end#Friendship

class Request
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :state, type: String, default: 'pending'

  belongs_to :requested_by, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :requests_from
  belongs_to :requested_to, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :requests_to

  validates :state, inclusion: { in: ["pending", "accepted", "rejected"]}
  ...
end#Request
```

I hope this helps.