# Rails has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship, activemodel

I'm trying to create a rails app where user can create events and invite participants to it and need your help!
I've been going in circle, trying few things but doesn't seem right at all and this is now driving me crazy!!
I'm using rails 4.

How would you setup the active model?

```
User
has_many :events through :meeting   //for the participants?
has_many :events     // for the organizer?

Event
belongs to :user
has_many :participants, class_name: "User"


Participant
belongs to :user
has_many :events through :meeting

Meeting
has_many :participants
has_many :events
```

Does that make any sense?
Do I need the Participant Model or am I just over-engineering it?
I guess I'm a bit confused with organizer is a user and participants are also users and meeting needs both organizer and participants so not so clear how to make this work...

Also read I could build the meeting relationship only when participant has been added. Would that be the way to go?
Thank you!

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806860/rails-associations-users-has-many-users-through-comments/21807202#21807202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need a participant model. This is the structure I'll use if there is some extra information I want to store in the meeting model. If not you can directly use has_and_belongs_to_many.

```
User
has_many :meetings
has_many :attending_events, through: :meetings, source: "Event"   //for the participants
has_many :events     // for the event organiser

Event
belongs to :user // The organiser
has_many :meetings
has_many :participants, through: :meetings, source: "User"  

Meeting
belongs_to :participant, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :attending_event, class_name: "Event" // Use attending_event_id as foreign_key
```

Comment: great. I'm almost there! one clarification though. For the Meeting, should it be
    Meeting
    belongs_to :event

or belongs_to :attending_events ?

and I guess my Meeting migration should have :participant_id and attending_event_id right?  and not user_id event_id ?  thanks again

Comment: You can use that to make it more semantic. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: had few more issues with it but finally got it to work.
need to use source instead of class_name for has_many through, in meeting it should be belongs_to :event instead of attending_event, class_name not needed for participants in Event.

This questions really helped me to make it work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621630/rails-activerecordhasmanythroughsourceassociationnotfounderror-could-not-fin

Comment: I've edited my answer as per your comments so that it can help other people.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need the `Participant` model:

```
User
has_many :meetings
has_many :events, through: :meetings

Event
has_many :meetings
has_many :participants, through: :meetings, class_name: "User"

Meeting
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event
```

From an instance of `User` you can do:

```
user.events # => List of Events
```

And from an instance of `Event` you can do:

```
event.participants # => List of Users
```

The [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) explanation in Ruby Guides is similar to what you want to do, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to do:

```
has_many :events
has_many :events #doesn't matter that it's a through table
```

I've done this in the past and did...

```
User
  has_many :invites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :invited_events, through: :invites, source: :event

Event
  has_many :invites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :invitees, through: :invites, source: :user

Invite
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
```

Then in the invite join table, have a boolean column for `creator` to know if that user created the event.  You can also add a column to show whether the user accepted the invite or not (to show participation).

Clean and simple has_many through... not complex =)