# Which assosciation to use in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `user` and `project` model created in `Rails`. I have to perform an association that will create an relationship which is described below:

```
1 User has many Projects

1 project has many Users
```

How can I go about creating an association for the same in `Rails`? I need some help on which type of association in rails will help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically trying to have a `many-to-many` relationship.

In Rails you can do this based on two association concept:

1. [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)  (HABTM)
2. [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

**Note:**

You should have `HABTM` if you just do not care about the way these two tables are joined (relationship model) and you do not want to have any logic/validation for your join data. It will just keep your foreign keys in a table and based on that data will be fetched.

You need `has_many :through` if you want to have an intermediate model in between `Project` and `User` which can be called as `UserProject` model. This way your association could look like as follows:

*User Model:*

```
has_many :user_projects
has_many :projects, through: :user_projects
```

*Project Model:*

```
has_many :user_projects
has_many :users, through: :user_projects
```

*UserProject Model:*

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
```

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a **many-to-many** relationship type. Rails allows you to create this relationship using `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` directives. You can learn the difference [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many).

Shortly, `has_many :through` allows you to add additional columns into the intermediate table, `has_and_belongs_to_many` doesn't. If you don't need to have additional attributes in the intermediate table than use `has_and_belongs_to_many` syntax. You can always change to `has_many :through` later.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use has_and_belongs_to_many or has_many through.Here is the link I am providing which will help you to sort out difference between them and which one will be good for you.Here is the video tutorial for you [association](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx8YTwtqRpI).ALso there is a good link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802445/rails-has-many-through-association).In your case you need has and belongs to many

Answer (score 0):

You may want too use `many to many` relationship between project and user. on top of that you may want to visit rails official guide which describes all of these relations in great detail.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in this situation is ,
In your user.rb model file:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

and In your project.rb model file:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```